# Data not parsing fully via webview/other html converting method in android app

Tags: android, html

I have created an app which works on transaction.In this app i am sending a request to the API used for transaction in which various values are sent.
The response is in the form of HTML. I am parsing the response but the response is not converting fully.

**Help me regarding this code and if any other method present to sent variables to a url via post only**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use webview to view the result and pass all of your values via url. You can achieve this as

```
    WebView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
```

postData is string for parameters.